# After append() how to bind a click event to just added element

Tags: jquery, click, append

I have this code

```
$(".delete2").click(function() {
  $('#load2').fadeIn();
}
```

I have dynamically added item via this return

```
addSubcategory = function(){
        sucategorynameval = $("#sucategoryname").val(); 
        categoryId        = $("#addcategoryid").val(); 
        $.get("process-add-subcat.php", { "action": "add_subcategory", "sucategoryname": sucategorynameval, "categoryId":categoryId },
               function(data){
                 //$("#main-cat-"+categoryId).load(location.href+"&pageExclusive=1 #main-cat-"+categoryId+">*","");
                 $("#main-cat-"+categoryId).append(data);
                 $("#addcategoryid").val(''); 
                 $("#sucategoryname").val(''); 
               });
```

The returned data contains `delete2` classed item.

How do I apply the click event to the newly added item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can just rebind it with the same click function you have used before or you use .live() http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$(".delete2").click(function() {
    $('#load2').fadeIn();
}
```

with

```
$(".delete2").live('click', function() {
    $('#load2').fadeIn();
});
```

This way the click event is bound to all existing an in the future created elements with class `.delete2`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(<parent selector>).on('click', '.delete2', function() { alert('test'); });
```

Change the parent selector to the id or class of the parent element

Comment: This code is not an answer to Pentium10 question. Please describe and give the proper code